# Search algorithm on Android: stack or preallocated buffer?

Tags: android, algorithm, recursion, stack

I am developing a pathfinding algorithm for an Android game, and I can write a recursive version (which is nice, but needs a big stack, so I might need to create a dedicated Thread for this with bigger stacksize), and a "loop" version which uses a buffer (instead of recursion). It is also a big problem that I don't know the size of the buffer in advance, so currently only the stack-based solution looks feasible.

I know this may be an algorithm theory or general computer science question, but perhaps it's Android specific because the stack size is a system-specific feature after all.

Generally, which should be more efficient (speed) on Android? The stack one, or the one which relies on buffer (heap)? Note that the question approaches the problem architecture-wise (assuming that the algorithmic complexity doesn't depend whether the algorithm is recursive or loop-based).

Comment: `so I might need to create a dedicated Thread for this with bigger stacksize` I'm not sure Android will let you do that...

Comment: Yeah, Thread has a constructor with a stacksize parameter, but the official docs say that this is platform-dependent and may be totally ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked for a Android specific answer, but I don't think it's really relevant to your problem. Two remarks

1. You don't necessarily need a stack based solution to implement a
   recursive algorithm, you can emulate the stack on the heap with a
   stack based data structure. Some times you don't even need this, though. This takes a bit more work, but don't base your algorithm on artifical architectural constraints.
2. There are plenty of non-recursive pathfinding, shortest path algorithms, ie [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

I can't comment on whether the most optimal recursive solution to a problem is going to be better than the most optimal iterative solution on Android.  Usually, all other things being equal, the iterative solution is going to be faster, but when you get to more complex algorithms than say, Fibonacci numbers, implementing an iterative algorithm recursively or vice-versa might make a difference.

Comment: Emulating the stack is no option because it would mean object instantiation I guess, which cannot be done due to the need of a seamless uninterrupted rendering of the game. But it's a good reminder, thanks. As for the algorithm, a variant of A* is used. Actually, my question is that an (architecture) stack-based solution is faster than one that manipulates a pre-allocated buffer in the heap? Probably this is a too general question, so let me rephrase: is stack access faster on Android than heap access?

Comment: "which cannot be done due to the need of a seamless uninterrupted rendering of the game" - I don't understand this part. How is object instantiation different from any other calculation?  I would guess stack access is faster. I don't have much GFX or performance tuning experience,  but my intuition is that this isn't going to be your bottleneck

Comment: Object instantiation may cause GC (since new objects are created, therefore old one might be collected, to put it simple). And GC (except GC_CONCURRENT) may stop a rendering thread for hundreds of milliseconds, causing a lag in your game animations and graphics. So, yes, unfortunately it can be a serious bottleneck if we allowed it.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is you're about to commit the sin of early optimization. Do you have any calculations or measurements that indicate you'll run out of RAM?

I recommend that you use the simplest algorithm you can. You may however want to use AsyncTask so as not to freeze the UI, even for a second.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't mean RAM, I meant speed only. We use an own Thread in the game, of course, no the UI thread.

Comment: I may have misread your question. When you mentioned concerns about stack size, I assumed you feared you might run out of RAM. As for speed, any recursive algorithm may be implemented linearly, which would the same computational complexity, as you mention, but somewhat faster, depending on how the computation-to-recursion ratio.